# how to download live video from video streaming using php script?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have video streaming content from ip camera.
when the video is in progress, the icon idm appears and I tried clicking on the icon, the url will be downloaded like and it work until the page refresh or stopped

```
rtmp://192.168.137.1:5119/live/mrb_cam.flv
```

so i was thinking, how to download that using php. I tried this code:

```
function download()
{ 
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $tgl = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $data = $tgl.".flv";
    header('Content-type:video/flv');
    header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='.basename($data));
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($data)); 
    header('Pragma: public');
    echo file_get_contents($data); 

}
```

when i tried, it was only take 703 bytes and the video is blank.

Is it possible to do this using php? And if not how can i do that?.
Im sorry for my bad language, Thank you.

Comment: Yes, its possible but for downloading you probably need to push to background job queue or something like that. Also use curl rather to download data which might be the issue you are facing.

Comment: I've tried to use curl, but the result is the same. could you give me reference to do that? thank you

Comment: Problem seems to be you are using PHP inside controller, while it should be in some background task queue cause the function will never exit considering it's an rtsp stream. Try running php script natively off terminal first to test it out

Comment: i got the same result. i think my problem is how to do that in background task queue like @georoot said. honestly, i dont know  yet how to do that. can you give me an example to do that? thank you